# encrypt data in database using AES 256

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I am building an app whose purpose is to store user credentials like passwords, bank account pin numbers, SSN(Social Security Number), etc. I need to put AES 256 encryption. For this I downloaded AES Crypt source code and binary (Java) from [here](http://www.aescrypt.com/download/v3/java/aescrypt-java-3_2.zip). But I dont know how to start with it. Could you please guide me through it. Is the related recources available with this .zip file ?? If not, please mention what all things i need to impose AES-256. Please, please help me i need to implement this as early as possible.

Comment: Security features for such sensitive information is definitely _not_ something you should implement in a hurry.

Comment: @Elazar Yes ofcourse, i agree with you, but its not like you provide me the code and i just copy paste it and run the code. I want to start working on it ASAP...

Comment: You should work alongside an experienced security-aware developer. not ask for help on stackoverflow. If you can't, you should not try to implement it on your own. that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at **[SQLCipher: Encrypted Database](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/).**

**GitHub**
 Project : [android-database-sqlcipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher)